# Xquery append text to tag values depending of the element type

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to get the values of some elements and then some text needs to be added depending on the element, for example:

```
<elementType>a</elementType> 
<otherElementType>b</otherElementType> 
<elementType>c</elementType> 
<elementType>d</elementType>

$doc//*[self::elementType or self::otherElementType]/string()

"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
```

this returns the values but I don´t know how to get the values like this:

```
"a is an elementType"
"b is an otherElementType"
"c is an elementType"
"d is an elementType"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//*[self::elementType or self::otherElementType]
              /concat(., ' is a ', name(), '&#xA;')
```

**When this expression is evaluated against the following XML document** (the provided malformed fragment -- corrected):

```
<t>
    <elementType>a</elementType>
    <otherElementType>b</otherElementType>
    <elementType>c</elementType>
    <elementType>d</elementType>
</t>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
a is a elementType
 b is a otherElementType
 c is a elementType
 d is a elementType
```

Comment: thanks again Dimitre but what if I want diferent strings, I mean for elementType will be something like "string a" and for otherElementType will be "string b", not the "name", I guess the concat function should be inside the "[]" right? but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at XSLT with its rule-based processing, which seems to match the way you are thinking about your requirements:

Use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

to process all the elements, and then separate template rules to say how each kind of element is to be processed:

```
<xsl:template match="elementType">
  do one thing
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="otherElementType">
  do a different thing
</xsl:template>
```